# Best way to change display for a field?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a node display that shows about 20 different fields.
One of the fields is a list of years (multiple values). Instead of printing the list of years I would like to just show the first and last year, for example "1999-2005".

Views has a great formatter for those situations but I don't want to use views for the node display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to test the following simple formatter I put together for one of my projects - named mvspan (multivalue span). Soon after I wrote it, the specs of my client changed and I did not need it anymore, therefore it may need some more tests, therefore please accept it in its "as-is" shape.

It works for simple text or integer types, not date or datestamps, unfortunately. Feel free to shape it for your own needs.

It has two modes: displaying first/last values or min/max values. Plus, it allows you to set the delimiter to glue up the values.

mvspan.info:

```
name = Multi-value Span
description = "Formats multi-value fields to show first/last or min/max value spans."
core = 7.x
files[] = mvspan.module
```

mvspan.module:

```
<?php
 /**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_info().
 */
function mvspan_field_formatter_info() {
  return array(
    // the key must be unique, so it's best to prefix with your module's name.
    'mvspan_formatter' => array(
      'label' => t('Multi-value Span'),
      'field types' => array('text', 'number_integer'),
      'multiple values' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT,
      'settings' => array(
        'delimiter' => '...',
        'mode' => 'minmax',
      )
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_view().
 */
function mvspan_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  $element = array();
  $settings = $display['settings'];

  $delimiter = check_plain($settings['delimiter']); // The delimiter string in the settings form

  switch($settings['mode']){
    case 'minmax':
      $minv = NULL;
      $maxv = NULL;

      foreach($items as $delta => $item) {
        if(is_null($minv) || $item['value'] < $minv){
          $minv = $item['value'];
        }
        if(is_null($maxv) || $item['value'] > $maxv){
          $maxv = $item['value'];
        }
      }

      if($minv === $maxv) {
        $element[0]['#markup'] = $minv;
      } else {
        $element[0]['#markup'] = implode($delimiter, array($minv, $maxv));
      }

      break;

    case 'firstlast':
      reset($items);
      $firstv = $items[key($items)]['value'];
      end($items);
      $lastv = $items[key($items)]['value'];

      $element[0]['#markup'] = implode($delimiter, array($firstv, $lastv));
      break;
  }
  return $element;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_settings_form().
 */
function mvspan_field_formatter_settings_form($field, $instance, $view_mode, $form, &$form_state){
  $display = $instance['display'][$view_mode];
  $settings = $display['settings'];
  $element = array();

  // settings
  $element['delimiter'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Delimiter'),
    '#description' => t('Delimiter string to be inserted between min and max values.'),
    '#default_value' => $settings['delimiter'],
  );
  $element['mode'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Value handling'),
    '#description' => t('How multiple values will be managed: min/max or first/last'),
    '#default_value' => $settings['mode'],
    '#options' => array(
      'minmax' => t('Minimum/maximum'),
      'firstlast'  => t('First/last'),
    )
  );
  return $element;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_settings_summary().
 */
function mvspan_field_formatter_settings_summary($field, $instance, $view_mode) {
  $display = $instance['display'][$view_mode];
  $settings = $display['settings'];
  $summary = array();

  switch($settings['mode']){
    case 'minmax':
      $summary[] = t('<strong>Min/max</strong> values will be displayed');
      break;

    case 'firstlast':
      $summary[] = t('<strong>First/last</strong> values will be displayed');
      break;
  }
  $summary[] = t('using delimiter: "<strong>@delim</strong>"', array('@delim' => $settings['delimiter']));
  return implode('<br />', $summary);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across the theme_preprocess_field() function and got it working. But I feel it's not a slick solution:

```
function bartik_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
    if($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_mc_years') {
        if(count($variables['items']) > 1) {    
            $to_year = end($variables['items']);
            $mc_years = $to_year['#markup'] . ' - '.$variables['items'][0]['#markup'];

            //destroy the array and just set the string to position 0
            unset($variables['items']);
            $variables['items']['0']['#markup'] = $mc_years;
        }
    }
}
```