# Create a list of events where an event can have more than one date

Tags: views, datetime

I am looking to create a view list of upcoming events but where each event may have more than one date as below:

Event 1 - 12th Jan

Event 2 - 12th Feb

Event 3 - 12th Mar

Event 1 - 12th Apr

Event 4 - 12th May

Event 5 - 12th Jun

Event is a content type with a Date field of multiple number values.

Comment: Should be very easy - where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Related: [Display multiple values of a field in separated rows](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37335/display-multiple-values-of-a-field-in-separated-rows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the date field and then in that fields settings uncheck **Display all values in the same row** (found in the **Multiple Field Settings** section).

[image]