# Overwrite field theme function from within form alter

Tags: forms

I'd like to modify the html of a form field from hook_form_alter(). Any hook for this one?
[image]

Comment: Yes, that would be `hook_form_alter()`, as you've said. If you're having trouble implementing `hook_form_alter()`, it's very important that you edit the question to include your code, and describe **exactly** what isn't working. We can't write it for you, as I'm sure you know. Thanks

Comment: yes but in practice how do I change it? I've uploaded a screenshot of the structure. The issue us how to overwrite the field_multiple_value_form. When I tried to add another function at #theme the page was not respoding

Comment: See the answers to [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34848/best-way-to-change-display-for-a-field) for a couple of different methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question itself the answer, inside
 hook_form_alter use the following

```
$form['field_job']['und'][0]['#prefix'] = 'yours html'
```

and `$form['field_job']['und'][0]['#suffix']='yours close tags of html'` this html will wrap field.

Answer (score 1):

you just need implement hook_form_alter in your custom field and according [drupal form api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) change what you want :

**notice "&" before $from(call by refrence)**

**get your form id by view source of you page and search form `<from .... id="your-form-name"` ..../>**

```
function youmoudle_form_alter(&$form,$form_state,$form_id){

if($form_id=="your_form_name"){
// your change come here
}
}
```

Comment: I am using form alter. That's where I fetched the dpm() posted above. My issue is how to change a specific field.

Comment: @PotneySwitters what  field you want to change ?

Comment: @PotneySwitters , ok , it seems you edit the question and determined which field you like to change.

Comment: job_field. But any field would do :)